# Appium error: WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. when using js.executeScript("android: scrollTo", scrollObject);

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium

The following used to work with my code (list all testView elements on the spinner and choosing specific one):

```
    HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap();
            element = (RemoteWebElement) driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ListView"));
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String webElementId = ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId();
            scrollObject.put("text", prefix);
            scrollObject.put("element", webElementId);
            js.executeScript("android: scrollTo", scrollObject);

            List<WebElement> listsDropDown = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
                for (WebElement listdropdown : listsDropDown) {
                String list = listdropdown.getText();
                if (list.equals(prefix)) {
                    listdropdown.click();
                    log.info(prefix + " chosen - Done.");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

But now it seems like something was changed and it fails on:

```
js.executeScript("android: scrollTo", scrollObject);
```

I am using Appium 1.3.7

Any one have any idea why it is happening?

Comment: BTW: No errors appears on Appium logs.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that there was indeed a bug in my appium version. 
I have been using this:

```
   js.executeScript("android: scrollTo", scrollObject);
```

And it worked well, but then something broke somewhere, so to fix it I changed to:

```
   js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
```

Problem solved.